# "Есть много вариантов, это всего лишь один из" -- грамотно ли?

Tags: грамматика, предлоги, заимствования

Довольно часто я слышу в устной речи фразы с предлогом, после которого опущено существительное, например,

> "Есть много вариантов..., это всего лишь один из *(них)*.

Это грамотно? Это недавняя тенденция? Эта конструкция строится на английский манер?

Answer (score 1):

Я бы это отнёс к разговорным выражениям сниженного стиля. При письменной передаче такой речи предлог нужно брать в кавычки, чтобы обозначить условность и передать интонацию такого выражения. Влияние английского вполне вероятно: на нём (по крайней мере, персонажи) зачастую ставят вопросы в форме незаконченного повествовательного предложения с вопросительной интонацией (напр. в конце такого "вопроса" ставится "потому что... ?", а вопросительное слово в нём отсутствует) ". Часто встречается ужасное заимствование вопроса '- And?' в форме агрессивно звучащего "- И?" (вместо "И что?"), видимо проникает через переводы фильмов. Как невежливое понукание в русском воспринимаются и давно примелькавшиеся переспросы с пропуском вопросительного слова (напр. "- В смысле?" вместо "В каком смысле?").

Answer (score 0):

Нет, в русском языке такое грамматически не верно. Но как умышленный эрратизм вполне допустимо.

Comment: Кроме, разве что, в стихах Бродского - недопустимо.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Пожалуйста, поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: В данном случае это самодостаточно, обоснования не требуется. Грамматика очевидная плюс личное мнение.

Comment: Не только Бродского. Но вообще - согласен. Да, у поэтов всяко бывает.